# Could you suggest a basic structure for an Angular application?

Tags: angularjs

The more I dive into Angular, the less I understand why to bind a controller to a specific route if you create directives with controllers, and `link`.

**app.js**

```
(function(){

angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
   .when('/', { 
         templateUrl : 'home.template.html', 
         controller : 'HomeController' 
        })
   .when('/about', { 
         templateUrl : 'about.template.html', 
         controller : 'AboutController' 
        });

}]);

})();
```

**home.controller.js**

```
(function(){

angular.module('app')

.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope){

}])

.directive('container', function(){
//Handle container element
  return {
   restrict : 'E',
   controller : ['$scope', function($scope){
     this.name = "My Name";
     this.setName= function(name){
       this.name = name;
     }
  }; 
   }],
   link : function(scope, element, attrs){
     //Do some linking...
   }
})
.directive('element1', function(){
//Handle element1 
   return {
    restrict : 'E',
    require : '^container',
    link : funciton(scope, element, attrs, ngContainerCtrl){
       scope.setName = ngContainerCtrl.setName();

    }



   };

})
.directive('element2', function(){
//Handle element2
);

})();
```

It seems like the controller linked to the view has no interest anymore.
Except for global methods, variables,... who still could be in an global container directive. Plus one's in a global directive, you can access his controller within a child directive.

**The problem is**

How should I structure that?
I loose the ability of downloading the controller only when the user is on one root.
With all directives I have to link them all in the index.html file and everything loads, even if not needed.

Comment: Check this http://www.johnpapa.net/structuring-an-angular-project/

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. It is recommended to set all controllers and directives from one page into a folder. Otherwise, for big applications, you'll get confused

Comment: yup it depends, if app you are creating is relatively small this method is feasible. On the given page there is also one link on refactoring angular app which exactly mentions your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There's a major difference between directives and controllers. The controller of a view deals with the business logic of that view. You might need to fetch some data from the server and format it in specific objects/arrays. All this stuff goes in the controller. You DO NOT do any dom manipulation in your controller. This is considered as bad practice.

Directives are used for DOM manipulations primarily but there are few other uses as well. Examples of directives could be your custom Tabs directive or your scrollable list or your drag-drop control or your fancy username available for use inputbox. These are all examples where you either created a reusable and complex dom object or tweaked the existing dom object to augment it's capabilities.

Comment: So if I need to fetch data, I make a factory and fetch it from the controller? Only example I can find usefull to controllers

Comment: Yes. What else do you want to do in your controllers? All the "Business Logic" goes in your controllers - that means filtering stuff, changing state of objects (to save them) etc. Also, all the CRUD operations happen from controllers. Think of controllers as .Net code behind classes and directives as reusable components, if you know .Net.

Comment: If I need data on one page, I do a resolve on the route, wich uses a Service, and pass this data in the controller. The controller is only linking the scope with this data. But that doesn't seem to be all he can do...

Comment: All right then... (I create a filter for filtering stuff, again not in the controller)

Comment: Well, I used the term filtering to mean playing with objects/lists to expose only relevant parts to bind to the page. There are times when you can use angular filters but at other times your put this logic in your controller.